# Find the vector normal to the plane (with positive z-component)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Consider the plane:
x+y+z=D
Find a unit vector normal to the plane with positive z-component.

I am mostly confused by the "positive z-component" statement... How would you find the normal unit vector?

Comment: If $u$ is normal to a plane, then so too is $-u$.  If $\|u\| = 1$, then so too does $\|-u\|$.  If the $z$-component of $u$ is negative, then the $z$-component of $-u$ is positive.

Comment: In other words, to add to the excellent comment above from @XanderHenderson, the question "find a unit normal vector to the given plane" has two answers, and they want you to to provide the one whose $z$-component is a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could find two vectors in the plane and take the cross product to find a normal vector.

Or, more easily, you can use the fact that the coefficients on $x,y,z$ define a normal vector and divide by its magnitude to get a unit vector.